# Get text from index multi select Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the index of the option user clicked on, now I want to get the text to make sure its a specific value.

I have tried

```
var x = $('#myMulti option[index=' + clickedIndex + ']');
alert (x.text())
```

I get an alert box with no text in it.

Comment: You're looking for [.eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `:eq` selector to target element by its index:

```
var x = $('#myMulti option:eq(' + clickedIndex+')');
```

Comment: Thanks you very much milind, that was it, it has solved my problem.

Comment: @Philosopher: i did not get you?? are you asking about marking question.

Comment: Your answer has solved my problem, i am new to stackoverflow, i wanted to makr your answer as correct answer

Comment: @Philosopher: You already marked it :) . Have a look at this thread http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

try this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r4zq2/1/)

```
  $("#fm_delivery_or_collection option:selected").each(function () {
   var $this = $(this);
   if ($this.length) {
    var selText = $this.text();
    console.log(selText);
   }
});
```